# Recieving Object instead of String from server?

Tags: android, spinner, android-volley

Am trying to connect service with volley and bind that value to spinner but when i tried to set adapter is showing object value not getting string don't know where am making mistake this is my code:

```
  final   Spinner spinner=(MaterialSpinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        String Url = "http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx/xxx/CRM/AcoountCreatePageLoad.svc/Account/AccountPageLoad";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url, new JSONObject(),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        String server_response = response.toString();
                        try {
                            JSONObject json_object = new JSONObject(server_response);
                            JSONArray json_array = new JSONArray(json_object.getString("AccountPageLoadResult"));
                            for (int i = 0; i < json_array.length(); i++) {
                                Model_Spinner_yog model_spinner_yog = new Model_Spinner_yog();
                                JSONObject json_arrayJSONObject = json_array.getJSONObject(i);
                                model_spinner_yog.setName(json_arrayJSONObject.getString("Name"));
                                yog.add(model_spinner_yog);



                            }

                            ArrayAdapter<Model_Spinner_yog> yogs=new ArrayAdapter<Model_Spinner_yog>(Create_Account.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,yog);
                            spinner.setAdapter(yogs);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

My model class:

```
public class Model_Task_List implements Serializable {


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Model_Task_List(int id, String subject, String userid, String taskStatus, int taskID, String userName) {
        this.id = id;
        Subject = subject;
        TaskID = taskID;
        TaskStatus = taskStatus;
        this.userid = userid;
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public int id;
    public String UserName;
    public String Subject;
    public String TaskStatus;

    public int getTaskID() {
        return TaskID;
    }

    public void setTaskID(int taskID) {
        TaskID = taskID;
    }

    public int TaskID;
    public static String KEY_table="task";
    public  static String KEY_id="id";
    public  static String KEY_username="name";
    public  static String KEY_subject="subject";
    public  static String KEY_task="status";
    public static String KEY_taskid="taskid";
    public static String KEY_owner="owner";

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String userid;

    public String getSubject() {
        return Subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        Subject = subject;
    }

    public String getTaskStatus() {
        return TaskStatus;
    }

    public void setTaskStatus(String taskStatus) {
        TaskStatus = taskStatus;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public Model_Task_List(String subject, String taskStatus, String userName) {
        Subject = subject;
        TaskStatus = taskStatus;
        UserName = userName;
    }
    public Model_Task_List(){

    }
}
```

Response:

```
{"AccountPageLoadResult":"[{\"PairLinkID\":126,\"Name\":\"Andhra Pradesh\",\"RID\":0,\"PID\":0,\"Status\":true,\"Description\":\"Andhra\"},{\"PairLinkID\":127,\"Name\":\"Delhi\",\"RID\":0,\"PID\":0,\"Status\":true,\"Description\":\"Delhi\"},{\"PairLinkID\":128,\"Name\":\"Gujarat\",\"RID\":0,\"PID\":0,\"Status\":true,\"Description\":\"Gujarat\"},{\"PairLinkID\":129,\"Name\":\"Haryana\",\"RID\":0,\"PID\":0,\"Status\":true,\"Description\":\"Haryana\"},{\"PairLinkID\":130,\"Name\":\"KARNATAKA\",\"RID\":0,\"PID\":0,\"Status\":true,\"Description\":\"Karnataka\"},{\"PairLinkID\":131,\"Name\":\"Kerala\",\"RID\":0,\"PID\":0,\"Status\":true,\"Description\":\"Kerala\"},{\"PairLinkID\":132,\"Name\":\"Maharashtra\",\"RID\":0,\"PID\":0,\"Status\":true,\"Description\":\"Maharashtra\"},{\"PairLinkID\":133,\"Name\":\"Punjab\",\"RID\":0,\"PID\":0,\"Status\":true,\"Description\":\"Punjab\"},{\"PairLinkID\":134,\"Name\":\"Rajasthan\",\"RID\":0,\"PID\":0,\"Status\":true,\"Description\":\"Rajasthan\"},{\"PairLinkID\":135,\"Name\":\"TAMILNADU\",\"RID\":0,\"PID\":0,\"Status\":true,\"Description\":\"Tamil Nadu\"},{\"PairLinkID\":136,\"Name\":\"Telangana\",\"RID\":0,\"PID\":0,\"Status\":true,\"Description\":\"Telangana\"},{\"PairLinkID\":137,\"Name\":\"Uttar Pradesh\",\"RID\":0,\"PID\":0,\"Status\":true,\"Description\":\"Uttar Pradesh\"},{\"PairLinkID\":138,\"Name\":\"West Bengal\",\"RID\":0,\"PID\":0,\"Status\":true,\"Description\":\"West Bengal\"},{\"PairLinkID\":214,\"Name\":\"\",\"RID\":0,\"PID\":0,\"Status\":true,\"Description\":\"\"}]"}
```

Comment: can you please post the response ?

Comment: am getting response properly but when i check the result can see only object value

Comment: Your response is already in JSONObject format you dont need to convert it into string and then again to JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

According to your Response you should not convert it into string and then again to JSONObject. Use Below code as a reference and make your code again.

```
 @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
       if(response != null){
        JSONArray array = response.optJSONArray("AccountPageLoadResult");
        for(int i = 0; i<array.length();i++){
           JSONObject object = array.optJSONObject(i);
           // get Other data from object using optString("name") or getString("name")
        }
      }
    }
```